# What is a keyboard shortcut in OSX for going a block up in text?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

In Linux while editing text, I can move block up and down with ctr+up arrow, ctr+down arrow.

What is the OSX equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what control+up does on other platforms, but if you (or other people searching for this question) mean scrolling a page up or down and moving the caret, you can use option+page up and option+page down. They don't work in web views or iWork applications though.

In TextMate you can make page up and page down move the caret by copying `/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Resources/KeyBindings.dict` to `~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/KeyBindings.dict` and adding this:

```
"\UF72C" = pageUp:;
"\UF72D" = pageDown:;
```

If you mean moving the caret multiple lines up or down, you can create `~/Library/KeyBindings/` and save a property list like this as `DefaultKeyBinding.dict`:

```
{   
    "^\UF700" = (moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:, moveUp:);
    "^\UF701" = (moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown:, moveDown:);
    "^$\UF700" = (moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:, moveUpAndModifySelection:);
    "^$\UF701" = (moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:, moveDownAndModifySelection:);
}
```

Or if you mean swapping the selected lines with the line above or below:

```
"^\UF700" = (selectParagraph:, setMark:, deleteToMark:, moveBackward:, moveToBeginningOfParagraph:, setMark:, yank:, moveBackward:, selectToMark:);
"^\UF701" = (selectParagraph:, setMark:, deleteToMark:, moveToEndOfParagraph:, moveForward:, setMark:, yank:, moveBackward:, selectToMark:);
```

See http://www.hcs.harvard.edu/~jrus/site/cocoa-text.html and http://lri.me/keybindings.html.